# Get VideoEntry by video id

Tags: java, youtube, youtube-api, gdata

I use Gdata for uploading my video on youtube. After uploading, I save video id and I want use this ID in future for retriving some information about my video (status, for example).

But how do this right? I have video id like - "tag:youtube.com,2008:video:VKm6-1jUgGc". I guess, real id is - VKm6-1jUgGc. But when I try do this:

```
createdEntry.getId(); //there I get video ID

videoEntry = service.getEntry(new URL("https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/uploads/videoid?v=" + "VKf6-1jUgOc"), VideoEntry.class);
```

I get error, that video id is incorrect!

Then, I try to use this:

```
createdEntry.getMediaGroup().getVideoId();
```

But this don't work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following request [(as stated here)](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_video_entries):

```
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/YOUR_VIDEO_ID?v=2
```